# Change a JLabel Text while an JButton listener is working

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JButton, lets call it "button" and added an ActionListener to it:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        call();
    }
});
```

It is correctly added to my frame etc. In that JFrame I also have a JLabel, and I want to change its text while the JButton method is working(because it takes ~30 secs to finish). How do I do that? Do I have to use some multi-thread-thingy? 
Here is the basic principle(the JLabel is called output):

```
public void call(){
    output.setText("test1");
    try { Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    output.setText("test2");
}
```

This will result in the "output" Label being changed to "test2" after one second. How can I make it instantly display "test1"?

Comment: Remove everything after `output.setText("test1");`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Thread.sleep(). This will prevent the GUI from repainting itself.

> Do I have to use some multi-thread-thingy?

Yes.

For a long running task you need to start a separate `Thread`, so the GUI can remain responsive.

In this case you can use a `SwingWorker`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and an example of using a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Well the thing is that it makes sense that the button stays in the pressed state while the method is working, since you can then 1) see when the script has finished 2) not press it again until it has finished

Comment: @Xerus, No it doesn't make sense. You should not design an application that freezes every time you invoke a long running task. If you want to give the user visual feedback then you should be using a `JProgressBar`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you! When I make a more complex project I'll look deeper into it